# Attach files for sending mail which are the result set of find command

Tags: shell-script, for, mailx

By using `find` command I got multiple files. Now I want to add all these files as mail attachment. How do I add these files as attachment in single mail?

I want to implement this in script. Do I need to use for loop and store the files in array variables?

EX: I got 3 files results by the following

```
find . -type f -name "sum*"
```

result:

```
sum123.pdf
sum234.pdf
sum453.pdf
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `mutt` like this:

```
mutt -a $(find . -type f -name "sum*")
```

If you want to do it non-interactive, try

```
mutt -s "Subject" -a $(find . -type f -name "sum*") -- user@cats.com < /dev/null
```

If `mutt` is not installed, [here](http://backreference.org/2013/05/22/send-email-with-attachments-from-script-or-command-line/) is an example with `mail` and more tools (e.g. `mpack`)!

So it should be something like

```
#!/bin/bash
# This needs heirloom-mailx
from="sender@example.com"
to="recipient@example.org"
subject="Some fancy title"
body="This is the body of our email"

declare -a attargs
for att in $(find . -type f -name "sum*"); do
  attargs+=( "-a"  "$att" )  
done

mail -s "$subject" -r "$from" "${attargs[@]}" "$to" <<< "$body"
```

For a sh environment without declare:

```
#!/bin/sh
# This needs heirloom-mailx
from="sender@example.com"
to="recipient@example.org"
subject="Some fancy title"
body="This is the body of our email"

attargs=""
for att in $(find . -type f -name "sum*"); do
  attargs="${attargs}-a $att "  
done
attargs=${attargs::-1}

mail -s "$subject" -r "$from" ${attargs[@]} "$to" <<< "$body"
```

Comment: can you install it? It's very useful in this situation.
Otherwise i'll try to find a `mail` equivalent.
What mail programs are installed on your system?

Comment: Have you tried the code above?

Comment: ah ok then use `attargs=()` instead of `declare -a attargs`. Do you use `bash` or `sh`? You can find it out via `echo $BASH`. I think `declare` is a `bash` builtin only.
If you run this step by step, better save this script as `mymail.sh` e.g., run `chmod +x ./mymail.sh` and finally `./mymail.sh`.

Comment: Did it work? If so, please accept the suggestion as solution, otherwise I am trying to refine the code to solve your issue.

Comment: It is showing like Syntax error at line 5 : `(' is not expected
line is: attargs=()

Comment: ok i'm trying to fix it

Comment: there is no whitespace between the `=` and `()`?

Comment: Yes, No white space between those two.

Comment: Ok try my new solution now, the one without declare and arrays :)

Comment: Thank you poly.
Now I am getting new error is 
"attargs=${attargs::-1}: 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command."

Comment: I am using ksh in my machine.

Comment: I tried using ksh on my script and it worked. Can you give me the output of `ksh -c 'echo $KSH_VERSION'`?

Answer (score 0):

```
ATTACH_FILE=`ls $HOME/data/*log.txt`
rmdat $HOME/file.dat
rmdat $HOME/sendemail.dat
ATTACH_FILE="$(echo $ATTACH_FILE | sed 's/ /\\n/g')"
export FILE=$HOME/file.dat
export FILE1=$HOME/sendemail.dat
echo $ATTACH_FILE >> $FILE
ATT_FILES=""
while read BP_fl
do

ATT_FILES=$ATT_FILES" uuencode  $BP_fl $(basename $BP_fl) ;"

done < $HOM/file.dat

echo '( echo "Hi" ; ' >> $FILE1
echo   $ATT_FILES >> $FILE1 
echo ') | mailx -m -s " automation test email" mxxxxx@abcdefg.com ' >> $FILE1

chmod 777 $FILE1
. $FILE1
```

Comment: would you please add some explanation into your answer which can help to better understand your script, thank  you